# Symfony 2 doctrine request object by Id giving blank page

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, fetch

When doing a simple query in the main controller such as:

```
public function newAdCreatedAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('websiteAdsBundle:AdsList');
    $article = $em->findById($id);

    return $this->render('websiteAdsBundle:Default:newAdCreated.html.twig',array('article'=>$article));
}
```

I've got a blank page in the log file I got the following message error (if that helps):

```
//Bunch of kernelerrors... here and then:
 [2014-06-09 14:07:53] doctrine.DEBUG: SET NAMES UTF8 [] []
 [2014-06-09 14:07:53] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2,t0.email AS email3, t0.telephone AS telephone4, t0.display_phone AS display_phone5, t0.title AS title6, t0.description AS description7, t0.country AS country8, t0.region AS region9, t0.department AS department10, t0.address AS address11, t0.city AS city12, t0.zip_code AS zip_code13, t0.status_pro AS status_pro14, t0.creationtime AS creationtime15, t0.updatetime AS updatetime16, t0.publication AS publication17 FROM AdsList t0 WHERE t0.id = ? ["53"] []
[2014-06-09 14:07:55] emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 125573121 bytes) {"type":1,"file":"/home/alfonso/sites/ads.website.com/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php","line":66} []
```

I think this is related to the @ORM\Join statement but I can't figure out what is it.
I guess with bidirectional associations, Twig’s dump is not working

the website/AdsBundle/Entity/AdsList.php class:

```
<?php

namespace website\AdsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos;

/**
 * AdsList
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="website\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsListRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
 class AdsList
 {


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $telephone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="display_phone", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $displayPhone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="region", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $region;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="department", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $department;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zip_code", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $zipCode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status_pro", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $statusPro;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="creationtime", type="datetime")
 */
private $creationtime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updatetime", type="datetime")
 */
private $updatetime;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="publication", type="boolean")
 */
private $publication;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos",mappedBy="adslist", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $photos;

/**
 * Set photos
 *
 * @param \website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setPhotos(\website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos = null)
{
    $this->photos = $photos;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photos
 *
 * @return \website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos 
 */
public function getPhotos()
{
    return $this->photos;
}

/**
 * Add photos
 *
 * @param \website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function addPhoto(\website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos)
{
    $this->photos[] = $photos;

    $photos->setAdslist($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove photos
 *
 * @param \website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos
 */
public function removePhoto(\website\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos)
{
    $this->photos->removeElement($photos);
}

public function __construct() {
    $this->creationtime=new \Datetime;
    $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set telephone
 *
 * @param string $telephone
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setTelephone($telephone)
{
    $this->telephone = $telephone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telephone
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTelephone()
{
    return $this->telephone;
}

/**
 * Set displayPhone
 *
 * @param string $displayPhone
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setDisplayPhone($displayPhone)
{
    $this->displayPhone = $displayPhone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get displayPhone
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDisplayPhone()
{
    return $this->displayPhone;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * Set region
 *
 * @param string $region
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setRegion($region)
{
    $this->region = $region;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get region
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRegion()
{
    return $this->region;
}

/**
 * Set department
 *
 * @param string $department
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setDepartment($department)
{
    $this->department = $department;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get department
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDepartment()
{
    return $this->department;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->city = $city;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * Set zipCode
 *
 * @param string $zipCode
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setZipCode($zipCode)
{
    $this->zipCode = $zipCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get zipCode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getZipCode()
{
    return $this->zipCode;
}

/**
 * Set statusPro
 *
 * @param string $statusPro
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setStatusPro($statusPro)
{
    $this->statusPro = $statusPro;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Get statusPro
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getStatusPro()
{
    return $this->statusPro;
}

/**
 * Set creationtime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $creationtime
 * @return test
 */
public function setCreationtime($creationtime)
{
    $this->creationtime = $creationtime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get creationtime
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreationtime()
{
    return $this->creationtime;
}

/**
 * Set updatetime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatetime
 * @return Test
 */
public function setUpdatetime($updatetime)
{
    $this->updatetime = $updatetime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatetime
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdatetime()
{
    return $this->updatetime;
}

/**
 * Set publication
 *
 * @param boolean $publication
 * @return test
 */
public function setPublication($publication)
{
    $this->publication = $publication;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get publication
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getPublication()
{
    return $this->publication;
}

// Callback
/**
* @ORM\PreUpdate
*/  
public function udpateDate()
{
     $this->setUpdatetime(new \DateTime());
}
}
```

And the photos class is the following:

```
<?php

namespace website\AdsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


/**
 * Photos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="website\AdsBundle\Entity\PhotosRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Photos
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="website\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList", inversedBy="photos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adslist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $adslist;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo_path", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $photoPath;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail_path", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $thumbnailPath;


/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
 private $file;

private $tempFilename;

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $this->file = $file;

    if (null !== $this->photoPath) {
      $this->tempFilename = $this->photoPath;
      // reset values
    }
}

public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set photoPath
 *
 * @param string $photoPath
 * @return Photos
 */
public function setPhotoPath($photoPath)
{
    $this->photoPath = $photoPath;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photoPath
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPhotoPath()
{
    return $this->photoPath;
}

/**
 * Set thumbnailPath
 *
 * @param string $thumbnailPath
 * @return Photos
 */
public function setThumbnailPath($thumbnailPath)
{
    $this->thumbnailPath = $thumbnailPath;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get thumbnailPath
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getThumbnailPath()
{
    return $this->thumbnailPath;
}

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if($this->file === null){
        return;
    }

    //$this->extension = $this->file->guessExtention();  // In my case I don't need it
    $this->photoPath = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
}


/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if($this->file === null){
        return;
    }

    if(null !== $this->tempFilename)
    {
        $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempFilename;
        if(file_exists($oldFile)){
            unlink($oldFile);
        }
    }


    $this->file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id.'.'.$this->photoPath
    );        
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function PreRemoveUpload()
{        
    $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.''.$this->photoPath;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if(filex_exists($this->tempFilename))
    {
        unlink($this->tempFilename);
    }
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
    return '/upload/img';
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getPhotoPath();
}

public function getMyWebPath()
{
    return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getPhotoPath();
}

/**
 * Set adslist
 *
 * @param \website\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList $adslist
 * @return Photos
 */
public function setAdslist(\website\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList $adslist = null)
{
    $this->adslist = $adslist;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adslist
 *
 * @return \website\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList 
 */
public function getAdslist()
{
    return $this->adslist;
}
}
```

EDIT:

I add the piece of twig template asked by bartek:

```
<body class="metro">
    <div class="page secondary">
            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="div_header">
                    <img class="logo" src="{{ website_path_swap }}/files/images/logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="div_header">
                    <h2 class=""></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-region">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <div>
                            {{ dump(article) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You've probably used `{{ dump() }}` in your `template`

Comment: Yes I did. Why we sould not? Is not dump done to see what is inside an object? also when var_dump($ads) in the php controller the page gets stuck loading for ever... it's like it's calling whe whole symfony2/doctrine.. I do not get it.

Comment: If you execute `dump()` it will dump all variables from the current context (~119 MB in your case). Can you show fragment of your template where you execute `dump`?

Comment: I don't understand why it has this behaviour. Obviously I only one to call a particular object(an adslist with its photos). I am adding the template but it is quite simple it's a bunch of divs and I launch {{ dump(article) }} or an "ad" I put article in this example but it should be "ad".

Comment: IMO dumping `ad` will involve dumping all `Photos` which will trigger dumping all related `Ads`. Use debugger instead of `var_dump driven development` ; ) You can also increase your php memory limit, but it would be hard to read the output of huge dump.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to symfony What is var_dump driven development? (I suppose this is not the php var_dump right?)

Comment: There's no such thing as `var_dump driven development`. It's a kind of joke ; ) `var_dump` is helpful when you don't have to debug big structures, just simple objects.

Comment: On topic about `dump`/`var_dump`: I would always suggest turning to `XDebug` and goint line-by-line. This method has many advantages over dumping, imho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intermediary answer:
for now I am using

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($article);
```

in order to get the output without problem. Apparently there are extensions that allows to echo the output in a more properly manner.

If I find something better I will come back to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

In case you ended up here using Symfony 2.6+, make sure you register the DebugBundle in your AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    //...

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        // ...
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```